# DBContext initing throws SocketException

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, npgsql, ef-core-2.2

I'm learning ef core and using it with PostresSQL. My project have following versions of packages:

Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 2.2.4
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.6
code of context:

```cs
using Shared;
using Shared.Gameplay.Organizations;

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Server
{
    public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
    {
        private static ApplicationContext _context;

        public static ApplicationContext Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_context == null)
                    _context = new ApplicationContext();
                return _context;
            }
        }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        public DbSet<VehicleState> Vehicles { get; set; }

        public DbSet<OrganizationBase> Organizations { get; set; }

        public ApplicationContext()
        {
            Database.EnsureDeleted();
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<IPenalty>()
                .ToTable("Penalties")
                .HasDiscriminator<int>("PenaltyType")
                .HasValue<WarnPenalty>(1)
                .HasValue<BanPenalty>(2);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasMany(x => x.Penalties)
                .WithOne(p => p.Player);
            modelBuilder.Entity<OrganizationBase>().Ignore(o => o.Actions);
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=usersdb;Username=postgres;Password=root", options =>
            {
                options.UseAdminDatabase("postgres");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Following code:

```
var db = ApplicationContext.Instance;
```

throws exceptions:

```
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 3D000: ���� ������ "usersdb" �� ����������
   at void Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector+<>c__DisplayClass161_0+<<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 1003
   at void Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector+<>c__DisplayClass161_0+<<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 1032
   at async Task Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 425
   at void Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection+<>c__DisplayClass32_0+<<Open>g__OpenLong|0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnection.cs:line 273
   at void System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
```

```
System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (10035): Операция на незаблокированном сокете не может быть завершена немедленно [::1]:5432
   at void System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
(SocketException: A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately [::1]:5432)
```

but after all opeartions seems to work succesfully and objects are created in DB.
Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Silly question - but is your database running, can you access it outside of your application?

Comment: @MarkDavies yeah, of course i can access. I tried pgAdmin and DBeaver. EnsureDeleted() and EnsureCreated() work fine.

Comment: No worries - jut wanted to make 100% sure - haha

Comment: Can i ask why you are doing `Database.EnsureDeleted();` & `Database.EnsureCreated();` in the constructor? Wondering if this is messing something up connecting to an all ready existing database deleting it, creating another one and then when your attempting to connect to it it's actually trying to connect to the old pipe

Comment: @MarkDavies hm. I found this example of code in one unofficial tutorial. I think this is useful to recreate db, because in active development i change model very often.
I tried to check whether connection is open when ctor called. It is closed.
Also I remove EnsureDeleted method but exception still throws.

Comment: May this be related to this issue: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1183

Answer (score 2):

According to [this Github issue](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1183), the exception is being thrown by .NET's socket API and is thrown every time the database connects. It's not anything to be concerned about and should be ignored.